# Как запустить драйвера написанные под XP на Win7

Tags: windows, драйвер

Есть у нас звуковая карта Creative SB 128. Под неё есть драйвера написаннные под XP. Можно их поставить на Win7?

Comment: Можно, но работать они не будут =)

Comment: Вызови контекстное меню. Раздел совместимость...  Далее поймёшь сам

Comment: Драйвера - очень низкоуровневая штука. Так что если они написаны для одной версии ОС, то 90% не пойдут на более свежих.